# Customizing Chart.js tool tips

Tags: tooltip, chart.js

```js
 <script>
 var  passings = [["New York","5001","05/18 00:36","S 28 MPH"], ["Phili","5002","05/18 01:36","S 50 MPH"],  ["Richmond","5003","05/18 02:36","S 40 MPH"], ["Wilson","5004","05/18 03:36","S 30 MPH"],
                  ["Savannah","5005","05/18 04:36","S 29 MPH"],  ["Miami","5006","05/18 05:36","S 40 MPH"]]
   
    leftK1 =  ["20","30","50","20","30","40"]
    var labelL1 = "Rain %";   

   
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
    var canvasWidth = 600;
   
    ctx.canvas.width = canvasWidth;
    ctx.canvas.height = 700;


    Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize = 14;
    Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = "Lato, sans-serif";
    var chartData = null;
    var chartOptions = null;
    
    var chartDataSets = [ {
      label : labelL1,
      fill : false,
      data : leftK1,
      borderColor : 'rgb(255, 99, 132)'
    } ];

    
    chartData = {
      labels : passings,
      datasets : chartDataSets
    }
    chartOptions = {
      responsive : true,
      maintainAspectRatio : false,
      elements : {
        line : {
          tension : 0, // disables bezier curves
        }
      },
      animation : {

      },

      legend : {
        display : true,
        position : 'top',
        labels : {
          fontColor : 'rgb(255, 99, 132)'
        }
      },
      title : {
        display : true,
        text : 'Passings Chart'
          },
      scales : {
        yAxes : [ {
          ticks : {
            max : 80,
            min : 0
          },
          gridLines : {
            zeroLineWidth : 5
          },
          scaleLabel : {
            display : true,
            labelString : "Rain Percantage",
            fontFamily : "Lato, sans-serif",
            fontSize : 18
          }
        } ],
        xAxes : [ {
          ticks : {
            autoSkip : false,
            maxTicksLimit : 15,
            maxRotation : 0,
            minRotation : 0,
            fontFamily : "Lato, sans-serif",
            fontSize : 12
          }
        } ]
      }
    // end scales
    }
    window.myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type : 'line',
      data : chartData,
      options : chartOptions
    });
              
         </script>
```

```html
 <h:form id="ChartForm">
    <div >  
      <canvas id="myChart"  ></canvas>          
     </div>    
  </h:form>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIwOR.png)I have passed Labels as an array to the chart (Chart.js version 2.7) so that I have multiple rows of X-Axis Labels. While displaying as tool tip, it is displaying whole array for each tool tip. I have seen several postings where they gave ways to display values from legend and and customizing Y-axis data.
Is there a way to display a short form of Label (X-axis label)  as tooltip ?

Comment: let us see your code so far

Comment: On Tool tips, I can see all values passed as labels like this
New York
5001
05/18 00:36
S 28 MPH

How can I just display New York and its value on tool tip
to get values I can use Call back methods, but display a part of label how can I manipulate

Comment: I hope you can find your answer below!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Callbacks as it is mentioned in [Chart.js Documentatoin](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#tooltip-callbacks)

You can even customize your tooltips for example:

```
var myPieChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'pie',
    data: data,
    options: {
        tooltips: {
            // Disable the on-canvas tooltip
            enabled: false,

            custom: function(tooltipModel) {
                // Tooltip Element
                var tooltipEl = document.getElementById('chartjs-tooltip');

                // Create element on first render
                if (!tooltipEl) {
                    tooltipEl = document.createElement('div');
                    tooltipEl.id = 'chartjs-tooltip';
                    tooltipEl.innerHTML = "<table></table>";
                    document.body.appendChild(tooltipEl);
                }

                // Hide if no tooltip
                if (tooltipModel.opacity === 0) {
                    tooltipEl.style.opacity = 0;
                    return;
                }

                // Set caret Position
                tooltipEl.classList.remove('above', 'below', 'no-transform');
                if (tooltipModel.yAlign) {
                    tooltipEl.classList.add(tooltipModel.yAlign);
                } else {
                    tooltipEl.classList.add('no-transform');
                }

                function getBody(bodyItem) {
                    return bodyItem.lines;
                }

                // Set Text
                if (tooltipModel.body) {
                    var titleLines = tooltipModel.title || [];
                    var bodyLines = tooltipModel.body.map(getBody);

                    var innerHtml = '<thead>';

                    titleLines.forEach(function(title) {
                        innerHtml += '<tr><th>' + title + '</th></tr>';
                    });
                    innerHtml += '</thead><tbody>';

                    bodyLines.forEach(function(body, i) {
                        var colors = tooltipModel.labelColors[i];
                        var style = 'background:' + colors.backgroundColor;
                        style += '; border-color:' + colors.borderColor;
                        style += '; border-width: 2px';
                        var span = '<span style="' + style + '"></span>';
                        innerHtml += '<tr><td>' + span + body + '</td></tr>';
                    });
                    innerHtml += '</tbody>';

                    var tableRoot = tooltipEl.querySelector('table');
                    tableRoot.innerHTML = innerHtml;
                }

                // `this` will be the overall tooltip
                var position = this._chart.canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

                // Display, position, and set styles for font
                tooltipEl.style.opacity = 1;
                tooltipEl.style.position = 'absolute';
                tooltipEl.style.left = position.left + tooltipModel.caretX + 'px';
                tooltipEl.style.top = position.top + tooltipModel.caretY + 'px';
                tooltipEl.style.fontFamily = tooltipModel._bodyFontFamily;
                tooltipEl.style.fontSize = tooltipModel.bodyFontSize + 'px';
                tooltipEl.style.fontStyle = tooltipModel._bodyFontStyle;
                tooltipEl.style.padding = tooltipModel.yPadding + 'px ' + tooltipModel.xPadding + 'px';
            }
        }
    }
});
```

See the [Samples](http://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/tooltips/callbacks.html)
and [more](https://codepen.io/k3no/pen/OReEKx)